# Regex Optional Match - split up simple select SQL with optional ORDER BY

Tags: sql, regex

Regex newbie question - I'm trying to split up a simple `SQL SELECT` query using regex, but I'm stuck with an optional `ORDER BY` clause.

For the SQL query `SELECT A, B, C FROM DB.TABLE ORDER BY D, E, F;`, I have the regex

`^SELECT\s+(?P<columns>.*)\s+FROM\s+(?P<table>.+?(?=ORDER BY))(?:ORDER BY)?(?P<order>.*);` which captures the column names, table name and columns under `ORDER BY` clause.

I want the `ORDER BY` clause to be optional but removing it from the query prevents a match. How do I fix this?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try this `SELECT\s+(?P<columns>.*)\s+FROM\s+(?P<table>.+?)\s*((?:ORDER BY)\s*(?P<order>.*))?;`

Comment: Thanks a ton! I looked it up on https://regex101.com/ and now understand how it works.